# How to customize sort action in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, customization, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin.  Unfortunately I can't get to override a sort action on a specific model. I just want to show all users (sort action, when the title is clicked) created_at 1 day ago or etc. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I am expecting that you want a custom filter which allows user to select options like "One Day Ago", "One Week Ago", "One Month Ago".

Yes you can implement this functionality using the scoping the queries. Here is the link for same. [Scoping Queries](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#scoping_the_queries)

Also if you want to customize the values displayed in the column the you can take a look at this [Railscast Active Admin Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin)

In this video they have explained the column customization for price column (from 4.25 to 7.15).

Comment: sorry, but i am using rails_admin, not active_admin